# Decorator for Java class with final methods

Tags: java, decorator, final

I have a (Java) class, WindowItem, that has a problem: One of the methods is not thread-safe. I can't fix WindowItem, because it's part of an external framework. So I figured I implement a Decorator for it, that has a "synchronized" keyword on the method in question.

The Decorator extends WindowItem and will also contain WindowItem. Following the Decorator pattern, I create methods in the Decorator that call the WindowItem it contains.

However, WindowItem has a few final methods, that I cannot override in the Decorator. That breaks the transparency of the Decorator. Let's make this explicit:

```
public class WindowItem {
   private List<WindowItem> windows;

   public Properties getMethodWithProblem() {
      ...
   }

   public final int getwindowCount() {
      return windows.size();
  }
}

public class WindowItemDecorator extends WindowItem {
   private WindowItem item;

   public WindowItemDecorator(WindowItem item) {
      this.item = item;
   }

   # Here I solve the problem by adding the synchronized keyword:
   public synchronized Properties getgetMethodWithProblem() {
      return super.getMethodWithProblem();
   }

   # Here I should override getWindowCount() but I can't because it's final
}
```

In my own code, whenever I have to pass a WindowItem somewhere, I wrapped it in a decorator first: new WindowItemDecorator(item) -- and the thread-safety problem disappears. However, if my code calls getwindowCount() on a WindowItemDecorator, it will always be zero: It executes getWindowCount() on the superclass instead of the "item" member.

So I would say the design of WindowItem (the fact that it has public final methods) makes it impossible to create a Decorator for this class.

Is that correct, or am I missing something?

In this case I might be able to keep a copy of the list of windows in the decorator, and keep it in sync, and then the result of getWindowCount() would be correct. But in that case, I prefer to fork and patch the framework...

Comment: Your first reflex is the right one but having the final methods makes it impossible to override them. Do you have to pass around/manipulate objects of type "WindowItem"? If not, you don't have to use the Decorator pattern. You can use composition and control the calls to the final methods of WindowItem by wrapping them in your new class that doesn't extend WindowItem but uses an instance via composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not thinking of the problem this way? Why not just handle the threading issues in your code, without assuming thread-safety of `WindowItem`.

```
// I personally prefer ReadWriteLocks, but this sounds like it will do...
synchronized (windowItem) {
    windowItem.getMethodWithProblem();
}
```

And then submit an RFE with the package maintainer to better support thread safety.

Indeed, if the class isn't designed to be thread safe, it is unlikely that a few `synchronized` keywords are going to truly fix things. What somebody means by "thread safe" is always relative ;-)

(Incidentally, `WindowItem` is definitely *NOT* thread safe as it is using `List` instead of explicitly using a "thread ready" variant [Correct way to synchronize ArrayList in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431681) - there are also no guarantees that the `List` is being accessed in a thread safe manner).

Comment: ... and ask them to implement an interface too, while you're at it. It never hurts (especially for mocking in unit tests).

Comment: If `interface`s are too heavyweight then at least remove the `final` modifier from such a trivial method. Or, at least be consistent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218744

Comment: The point of solving this problem using a decorator though, is that I solve the problem in one place, rather than having to fix all the uses of WindowItem in my code.

Comment: yeah, but sometimes we just got to take our medicine and admit that the underlying library is not thread safe. I'm not entirely convinced that synchronizing this one method would even fix that for you. For a start, `windows` isn't even `volatile`, never mind `final`, so `getwindowCount` can't **ever** be threadsafe unless the maintainer changes their code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could employ the [Delegation Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Java_examples), which would work nicely if the `WindowItem` class implements an interface defining all the methods you care about. Or if it doesn't break too much of your existing code to refer to this delegated class rather than `WindowItem`.

Comment: the problem is more subtle than that - there is no `interface` for `WindowItem` and he is handed the `WindowItem`s.

Comment: I believe what you're saying is to create a Decorator for an interface of WindowItem instead of for the class itself. I would agree to that, but in this case, there is no such interface.

Comment: @Paul Swing and a miss. There's just not enough interfaces in the world is there?!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, you can't override final methods, meaning that it's not possible to create a decorator for this class.

If you can override the method that has the problem, and solve the problem by synchronizing the method, you could just leave it at that. That is, just use your subclass, and not use the decorator pattern.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good solution if I were creating the WindowItem objects. Then, instead of creating a WindowItem object, I create a SyncedWindowItem, problem solved. Unfortunately, the WindowItem objects are created for me (it's not even a concrete class, it's abstract), so I can't do that on already existing objects.

Answer (score -1):

A coworker had an idea that I think can solve the problem. I can keep the state of the superclass and the state of the "item" member in sync by looking at all methods that modify the List windows. There are a few: addWindow, removeWindow. Instead of calling just "item.addWindow(...)" in the decorator, I call addWindow on the superclass as well:

Normal decorator:

```
public void addWindow(WindowItem newItem) {
   item.addWindow(newItem);
}
```

In this case I do:

```
public void addWindow(WindowItem newItem) {
   super.addWindow(newItem);
   item.addWindow(newItem);
}
```

That keeps the state in sync and the return values of the final methods correct.

This is a solution that can work or not work depending on internals of the class being decorated.

Comment: It's not a general solution, but in this case I believe it works, because I don't need to override any final methods if the internal state is in sync (in this case!). Note that the final method is getWindowCount(). If I make sure that the superclass has the same number of windows at the "item", then there is no need to override getWindowCount().

Comment: so basically, you're keeping two copies of the instance - one as delegate and the other as super - so that one returns the right answer for one method, and the other the right answer for all other methods plus the added thread safety logic? Enjoy maintaining that! :-)

Comment: Incidentally, you'll potentially have broken the thread safety of the class (assuming it had any) by having two versions which are prone to [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). And I trust nothing outside of your control ever has a reference to the original `WindowItem`?

Comment: No, I'm not going to enjoy maintaining that. But then again, even a plain old regular decorator is terrible for maintenance, because if a public method is added to the WindowItem class, one needs to remember to add it to the decorator. Which you won't. The reason, I think, you would still use a decorator is that the alternative is worse, which is to fix the bug in the framework, and maintain _that_.

Comment: *au contraire*! [`@Delegate`](http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html). And don't forget the *other* alternative, which is to maintain your own code without the assumption that the class is thread safe.