# Error adding objects to public arraylist in android application

Tags: android, dialog

I've extended `Application` and declared a `public ArrayList` there that I use to hold data (I know it's not as a Singleton in android should be, but it was the only thing I could make work).

**The problem :**
When I display my `CreateNewObject` dialog and press OK I get the following error.

**Error:**

```
10-30 10:20:19.069: E/AndroidRuntime(632): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.nuclear.gfr.adapter.PatientAdapter)]
```

My code:

```
public class NewPatientDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "NUKClear";

    OnNewPatientlistener listener;

    private NewPatientDialog() {

    }

    public interface OnNewPatientlistener {
        public void OnNewPatient(Patient newPatient);
    }

    public void addPatientAction(Patient patient) {
        OnNewPatientlistener activity = (OnNewPatientlistener) getActivity();
        activity.OnNewPatient(patient);
    }

    public static NewPatientDialog newInstance(String title) {
        NewPatientDialog frag = new NewPatientDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View newPatient = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_patient_dialog,
                null);
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating dialog for new patientinput...");
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setView(newPatient)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                final EditText name = (EditText) newPatient
                                        .findViewById(R.id.name_edit);
                                final EditText ssn = (EditText) newPatient
                                        .findViewById(R.id.ssn_edit);
                                final EditText accnum = (EditText) newPatient
                                        .findViewById(R.id.accnr_edit);

                                final Patient patient = new Patient(ssn.getText()
                                        .toString(), name.getText().toString(),
                                        new Study(SimpleDateFormat
                                                .getDateInstance().toString(),
                                                accnum.getText().toString()));

                                addPatientAction(patient); 

                                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(
                                        getActivity());
                                db.addPatientStudy(patient);

                                /*DataManager dm = new DataManager(getActivity()
                                        .getBaseContext());
                                dm.addPatient(patient);*/

                                /*
                                 * PatientManager pm = new
                                 * PatientManager(getActivity
                                 * ().getBaseContext()); pm.add(patient);
                                 */

                                // Interfacecallback
                                /*
                                 * OnNewPatientlistener activity =
                                 * (OnNewPatientlistener) getActivity();
                                 * activity.OnNewPatient(patient);
                                 */

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                dismiss();
                            }
                        }).create();

    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to circumvent this?

Comment: try making the arraylist synchronized.

Comment: I get the error:
Illegal modifier for the field Patients; only public, protected, private, static, final, transient & volatile are permitted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431681/correct-way-to-synchronize-arraylist-in-java see this

Comment: Not sure how this explains my problem, could you elaborate.

Comment: Found the solution. Had to add:
'runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      GFRApplication.dPatients.add(newPatient);
     }
   });'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding...

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  GFRApplication.dPatients.add(newPatient);
              }
            });
```

...did the trick.