# Synchronized objects while iterating ArrayList

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

Let's say i have the following scenario:

```
final int index = 10;
Phone phone = phoneList.get(index);
synchronized(phone)
{
   //some code runs here
}
```

So while the the phone object (which is got throught phoneList.get() method) is locked can another thread execute the method:

```
phoneList.remove(index);
```

and null the phone object at the given index?

Comment: Sure it can, why not? You're not synchronizing on list itself.

Comment: Yes It will...if you want avoid the same, then make syncronize on list...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431681/correct-way-to-synchronize-arraylist-in-java might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. why not?

But still, `phone` will be pointing to the same object. i.e. the object gets removed from list but the jvm still has reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

One operation has nothing to do with the other: `synchronized` doesn't protect access to any particular object. If your `remove` operation is within a `synchronized` block which uses the same object as the lock, then it will have to wait; if it isn't it will successfully remove the object, with no effect on the `synchronized` block which is using it as a lock. Removing the object from the list will not turn the object into garbage until its monitor is locked by any thread.

Comment: So should i synchronize first the list and then the phone object or before removing the phone object i have to lock it?

Comment: This cannot be answered in general, but if you are just removing an item from the list and not changing anything on the item itself, I don't see why you would lock on the item at all. But most importantly, you must understand your own application logic on one side and the precise semantics of Java's locks on the other, and then combine those two into a locking scheme which gives you full thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Since you are synchronizing on the `Phone` instance, this is possible. Another thread can remove the same `phone` object from the `ArrayList`. But your `phone` reference will be pointing to the same instance.

To ensure that no other thread can access your list from somewhere else, synchronize on the list itself -

```
synchronized(phoneList)
{
    //some code runs here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse. Locking `Phone` does *not* lock the List.

Also, to remove an element from the list you don't need to use the element. Removing is as simple as :

```
backingArray[i] = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, It just provides the `synchronization` for a group of statements inside `synchronized` and never cares about the `phone` instance obtained. Removing the `phone` object from the `phoneList` is possible. But remember **Java** does not delete an object from memory until it has some references left.

Answer (score 1):

When you do phoneList.get(index) it gives you the reference of the object from the list to Phone object.

Since only the phone object is synchronised you can remove elements from the list. Hence you will **NOT** get [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) when you try to remove elements from the list.

But if the reference is lost or null. The you might get [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) when you try to operate on the phone object.