# Synchronize block not synchronizing a Java array list

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a Java `ArrayList`, that is being used by 500+ threads simultaneously. For some reason, the synchronization block is not ensuring synchronization on a Java Array List. I known that `ArrayList`s are non thread-safe, *i.e.*, they are not synchronized. However, I thought that by wrapping the list into a synchronized block I would achieve that. Unfortunately, in rare (but in some situations) two or more threads are entering the synchronized block simultaneously, which is giving me non-deterministic behaviour. Am I missing something? How can I guarantee that my array list (or any other list collection) are completely thread safe throughout 500+ simultaneous threads operating in the array.

There is a related question, ([Correct way to synchronize ArrayList in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431681/correct-way-to-synchronize-arraylist-in-java)), but I did not understood its answer. Should I create a Synchronized collection at every "run" of my threads???

Sample:

Thread 1

```
synchronized (_myList) {
   Iterator it = _myList.iterator();
   ...
}
```

Thread 2

```
synchronized (_myList) {
   Iterator it = _myList.iterator();
   ...
}
```

Thread n

```
synchronized (_myList) {
   Iterator it = _myList.iterator();
   ...
}
```

Comment: You're synchronizing on `_myList` but then iterating over `_unackedSentQueue`... why? If two instances have different `_myList` references but the same `_unackedSentQueue` references, that will cause the problem you're seeing. Ideally, you should post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Fundamentally you should probably consider using a list implementation designed for this though...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you could use `Vector` if you need a synchronized variant of arraylist.

Comment: @kviiri: No, that only synchronizes each individual operation - it doesn't help if you're trying to synchronize a whole sequence of operations (like iterating).

Comment: If this list is used across all 500 threads you may make a similar global object lock `Object _unackedSentQueueLock = new Object()` then use that for your synchronized locks. Alternatively you could always just synchronize with the list your actually using `_unackedSentQueue`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change _unackedSentQueue to _myList (to make the smaple easier). In fact, I am synchronizing with _myList (_unackedSentQueue).

Comment: Are you at any place calling `_myList.wait();`?

Comment: Also, if you are using this ArrayList as a queue, are you aware that ArrayBlockingQueue exists, and is already fully thread-safe?

Comment: Post the code with the problem. Don't just post meaningless snippets.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 :**

Use a custom lock : 
`Object lock = new Object();`

and synchronize things over this lock like :

`synchronized(lock) { 
     //operations on array list
}`

**Option 2:**

Use `java.util.Collections.synchronizedList()`

Refer the following code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

    public class SynchronizedListExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<String> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

            syncList.add("one");
            syncList.add("two");
            syncList.add("three");

            // when iterating over a synchronized list, we need to synchronize access to the synchronized list
            synchronized (syncList) {
                Iterator<String> iterator = syncList.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("item: " + iterator.next());
                }
            }

        }

    }
```