# How to synchronize the ArrayList in my code without using Collections class?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, collections, synchronized

How can I rewrite my code without using concurrent collections?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<Integer> source = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    source.add(i);
}
List<Integer> synchList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

     Runnable runnable = () -> {synchList.addAll(source);}; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to synchronize ArrayList in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431681/correct-way-to-synchronize-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: Just replace `List<Integer> synchList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>( ));` with `List<Integer> synchList = new ArrayList<>();`. In the code you’ve posted, there is no need for any synchronization. If you want to do something different, post the relevant code instead of a pointless snippet.